# Using Linq to objects to get to an object deep in the hierarchy

Tags: linq

Quite new to Linq, and I'm struggling with this one. Basically I have a collection of "Workers", which each object itself contains a collection of "WorkerOperatorAssignments", which each object contains an "Operator" object.

> Workers (collection) -> WorkerOperatorAssignments (collection) ->
>   Operator (object)

I wish to return the Operator record in certain circumstances using Linq. I have the following so far:

```
Operator TillLogin = WorkersCollection.Where(w => 
    w.WorkerOperatorAssignments.Any(a => 
        a.Operator.TypeCode == OperatorTypeCode.TillOperator)
);
```

But this obviously returns a collection of workers which contain an Operator record as per the where clause. How do I return just that actual Operator record in this condition?

UPDATE:

Thank you all for the answers, helped me a bunch. I have amended my full query to:

```
Operator TillLogin = Response.Payload.Party.Workers
      .SelectMany(w => w.WorkerOperatorAssignments)
      .Select(a => a.Operator)
      .Where(o => o.TypeCode.Trim() == OperatorTypeCode.TillOperator)
      .SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get at the WorkerOperatorAssignments using a SelectMany...and then at the Operator using Select. Then you can just filter on the operators.:

```
 IEnumerable<Operator> tillOperators = 

 // flatten the WorkerOperatorAssignments
 WorkersCollection.SelectMany(w => w.WorkerOperatorAssignments)
   // get the Operator off each WorkerOperatorAssignment
   .Select(a => a.Operator)
   // filter the Operators
   .Where(o => o.TypeCode == OperatorTypeCode.TillOperator));
```

Comment: absolute genius, you've saved my sanity! Thanks a lot. I'll mark this as answer as I believe you were the first in. Although all other answers were good as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
var operators = 
    from worker in WorkersCollection
    from workerAssignment in worker.WorkerOperatorAssignments
    where workerAssignment.Operator.TypeCode == OperatorTypeCode.TillOperator
    select workerAssignment.Operator;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you all helped here

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want:

```
var tills = from worker in WorkersCollection
            from assignment in worker.WorkerOperatorAssignments
            where assignment.Operator.TypeCode == OperatorTypeCode.TillOperator
            select assignment.Operator;

var firstTillLogin = tills.First(); // Or whatever...
```

Note the final part, going from a sequence of *all* matching operators to just the first one. You may want First, `FirstOrDefault`, `Last`, `LastOrDefault`, `Single`, or `SingleOrDefault` - or maybe you just want to handle all of them. We can't really tell.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you all helped here

Answer (score 1):

```
Operator TillLogin = WorkersCollection
    .SelectMany(w => w.WorkerOperatorAssignments) //get all the worker assignments
    .Select(oa => oa.Operator) //from each select the operator
    .Single(o => o.TypeCode == OperatorTypeCode.TillOperator); //find the single operator that matches the code
```

This will throw an exception if there isn't a single operator with that type code. If you don't want to throw an exception, and instead have `TillLogin` be `null`, use `SingleOrDefault` (assuming Operator isn't a value type, otherwise it will be the default value).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you all helped here