# Is it possible to find(generically) an object with a GUID in a nested Class in C# using a LINQ to Objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-objects

I have a nested class hierarchy

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Models
{
public class Document
{
public Document();
public Guid ID { get; set; }
public List<Order> Orders {get; set;}
}
public class Order
{
public Order();
public Guid ID { get; set; }
public List<OrderItem> OrderItems {get; set;}
}
public class OrderItem
{
public OrderItem();
public Guid ID { get; set; }
public String ProductName { get; set; }
public int Qty { get; set; }
}
}
```

The IDs are GUIDs. I need to search generically to an object with a specified GUID. I have been advised that one approach is to specify an interface against the class for this (see: [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723426/is-it-possible-to-findgenerically-an-object-with-a-guid-in-a-nested-class-in-c)). However since my class is generated, I prefer to not alter the class. So I want to investigate an approach using LINQ to Objects. I have also found this excellent SO post on this approach: [LINQ to Objects SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507532/using-linq-to-objects-to-get-to-an-object-deep-in-the-hierarchy), but of course one needs to specify all the child classes in the query.

Optimistically I was hoping for "get me the object with the GUID of x". GUIDs are unique, so I felt I did not need to specify a pathway. However I guess this is not possible with LINQ???

EDIT: Updated code above. Apologies. I would like to extract An OrderItem with GUID= X

Comment: Please show at least compiling code. That looks like a mix between C# and VB.NET.

Comment: what's your problem with `document.Orders.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == yourGuid);`?

Comment: Hi All, Many thanks for help thus far. Apologies for brevity of code. I have now corrected. I have added an extra class "OrderItems" which I need to extract an object from using the OrderItem ID. Specifying the complete pathway seems to be the only way. The problem I was trying to get around is that there are other master detail entities in this objects, and therefore I was investigating whether there was a more generic way of getting to an object via it unique GUID without specifying all the constituent entities in the query like Order, OrderItems etc. I think the answer is no, like SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the modified question, the code to search for all matching `OrderItem` objects inside a list of documents would be like this:

```
List<Document> data = ...;
Guid guidToSearch = ...;
var orderItems = data.SelectMany(o => o.Orders)
                     .SelectMany(o => o.OrderItems)
                     .Where(o => o.ID == guidToSearch)
                     .ToList();
```

If you have just one document, not a list, you can skip the first `SelectMany` call.

Comment: @Knagis, Thanks for this. Very useful. Am I assuming correctly that "LINQ to Objects" is the recommended way to get into a complex structure of objects to do CRUD type operations on the structure?

Comment: LINQ to objects is the easy way of solving these things but it always depends on the specific situation - in many cases it is possible to find another approach that might be more performant or easier to read.

Comment: @Knagis, Thanks for this, really appreciated. Just had some great advice on implementing an interface on an abstract class which is inherited by Document. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a collection of different objects like this:

```
List<object> data = new List<object>() { new Order { ID = ... }, new Document { ID = ... } };
```

then you could write code like this

```
var guidToSearch = ...;
var results = data.Where<dynamic>(o => o.ID == guidToSearch).ToList();
```

thre `results` collection will now contain the matching objects.